# Recasting a STRING into a VALUE in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: python, python-3.x, libreoffice-calc, pyuno

I have a Python class that does some currency conversion and string formatting of numbers. It takes polymorphic input, but only spits out a stringified number. I can push those stringified numbers up to a LibreOffice Calc in Python easy enough:

```
stringifiednumber = str("1.01")
cell_a1 = sheet1.getCellRange("A1")
cell_a1.String = stringifiednumber
```

This actually works nicely since the builtin currency formats in Calc work just fine with stringified numbers.

What doesn't work is formulas, or sort of doesn't work. Calling `SUM(A1:A2)` will not see the stringified A1. There is a workaround (forgive me it is late and I forget it exactly but it is similar to:) `=SUMRECORD(VALUE(A1:A2))`.

As I understand it, each cell has a memory location for a number, a string, and a formula. The formula only acts on the `VALUE` memory location.

Through the spreadsheet UI, I can convert one cell type to another during a copy. To do that I just put the following formula in A2, and it converts `STRING(A1)` to `VALUE( A2)`:

```
# formula placed in A2

    =VALUE(A1)
```

but that only works by copying one cell to another. Obviously there is an internal recasting function within the spreadsheet that is doing the conversion during the copy.

What I want to do, is write a stringified number to the spreadsheet (as above) and then call the spreadsheets native recasting function in place from Python, so that VALUE(A1) is recast from STRING(A1).

If I knew what the recasting function was I could just call it after every string write. This would make macros in the UI work like the user expects them to work.

If your answer is: "do type conversion Python-side", I've already considered that, and it is not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Please clarify where `sheet1` is coming from. According to `Calc` API there is not a method `getCellRange` in a spreadsheet. There are only `getCellByPosition` to get a single cell and `getCellRangeByName` to get a cell range. And the single cell provides `setValue` and `setFormula` additional to `setString`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Title, multiply by `1`:

[image: Multiply text "6" by <code>1</code>]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Forgive my ignorance, but can you give me an example of telling Calc to multiply a cell by 1, in python. Or basic. I don't know whether you bind a forumula, or whether there is an API specific function or operator or what.